# Angular app deployed with Azure App Services cannot find an asset which it finds when using ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure, web-deployment

I have an Angular CLI built app, a script in 'src/app/text-gen/text-gen.component.ts' loads in a tensorflow.js model with:

```
this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('../assets/models/model.json');
```

Referring to a JSON in 'src/assets/models/model.json'.

When deploying this app with Azure App Services everything works but for some reason this model.json returns 404 Not Found:

[image]

When looking at the Kudu Console I can see model.json in 'site/wwwroot/assets/models/model.json'.

Also, in 'angular.json', my `"outputPath"` is set to `"dist"`.

I'm sure this is something very obvious - I'm very new to Angular, web-dev, Azure etc - but I can't seem to figure this one out!

Thanks!!!

Edit: Adding a screenshot of `model.json` in the Kudu console, I also tried `'/assets/models/model.json'` as the path and received the same error.

[image]

Comment: Probably should be `'/assets/models/model.json'`. You can test this by trying `http://meditations-ai.azurewebsite.net/assets/models/model.json` in your browser

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I tried this but it didn't work, `https://meditations-ai.azurewebsite.net/assets/models` works but with an access denied error 403 but typing the full path comes with 404 not found error - despite `model.json` being in that location - I've added a screenshot of it's location in SCM/Kudu

Answer (score 7):

I figured this out thanks to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570143/angular-app-on-azure-app-service-404-errors-when-loading-config-file-from-asse).

In the web.config file, I needed to add `<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /></staticContent>` just before the `<rewrite>` tag. Altogether giving a web.config file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

For anyone reading this in the future who is new to Angular like myself. The web.config file can be included within the `dist/` directory by adding it to `"assets"` inside angular.json, so my assets look like this for example:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/model.json",
  "src/char2idx.json",
  "src/web.config"
]
```